# How can I multiple foreach loopdata in same loop

Tags: php

How can I fetch data

1 user can many item

1 item can add many status item

User

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    TESTNAME      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

ITEM

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Item_id        |      name        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      ITEM1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

STATUS

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      status_id      |      name        |      item_id     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     status1      |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

USER_ADD_ITEM

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      User_item      |      user_id     |      item_id     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    1             |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I try to loop data by

```
my sql = SELECT * FROM USER_ADD_ITEM a 
         LEFT JOIN USER u ON a.user_id = u.id
         LEFT JOIN ITEM i ON a.item_id = i.id
         LEFT JOIN STATUS s ON a.item_id = s.item_id
```

I'm confusing now  did my database right?
how can I loop data with have status inside loop

Here is my html

```
<a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">ITEM_Name</a>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
 Item Status
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Now I've an araay  how can I echo array

```
a[0][name];
a[1][name];
```

I try to

```
foreach ($aa as $a) { $i++ ;
 echo $a[$i][name]
}
```

It's echo out only a[1] because I start at 1  How to fix this

Comment: What does your query returnS?

Comment: It's return every thing I want but I think i'm confusing about how to loop in html tag I'll edit add my html

Comment: If you're getting all the data you want, what's the problem? Displaying them in your site?

Comment: first I want to loop show only item name and inside loop Can I  loop to get status in  that item ? I mean i've to use 2 foreach loop I dnt know hwo to do it

Comment: Please post your php coding attempt.  Show us its output and show us your desired output.

Comment: I already updated

Comment: I try a lot of thing now i think it's work but cant print out  !

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `file.html` to `file.html.php`. Then you can use 
`<?php foreach($array as $key => $value) : ?>
<?= $value ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>`
inside of your html code.

Comment: first I want to loop show only item name and inside loop Can I loop to get status in that item ? I mean i've to use 2 foreach loop I dnt know hwo to do it

Comment: I don't realy get what you try to accomplish... Could you please post the array you have to loop trought?

Comment: If your array's name is $a, you have to make the foreach loop like that: `foreach($a as $x) { echo $x['name'] }`